# How to replace small alpha characters only to double byte using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to replace the small alpha characters only in SQL Server? For example If I have a text `A Simple Man`. The text should be replace to `A Söнрмï Mæо`. I use the script below the problem is the big letter was replaced also.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[sf_ReplaceCharacters] (@string NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tmpString NVARCHAR(100)
    SET @tmpString = @string 
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'a',N'æ')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'b',N'в')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'c',N'г')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'd',N'д')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'e',N'ï')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'f',N'ж')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'g',N'з')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'h',N'и')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'i',N'ö')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'j',N'к')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'k',N'л')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'l',N'м')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'm',N'н')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'n',N'о')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'o',N'Ą')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'p',N'р')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'q',N'с')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'r',N'т')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N's',N'у')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N't',N'ф')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'u',N'Č')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'v',N'ц')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'w',N'ч')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'x',N'ш')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'y',N'щ')
    set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString,N'z',N'ъ')
    RETURN @tmpString
END
```

Comment: You need to use the `collate` clause with a `cs` or `bin` collation.

Comment: Hi Martin, can you please give me an example on how to apply in my sample function created?

Comment: Would you please post the solution you found, It would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

As martin smith mentioned, I use collate to make the character replacement sensitive.

```
SET @tmpString = @string 
set @tmpString=replace(@tmpString COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AS,N'a',N'æ')
```